# What does this notation mean in PHP?

Tags: php

I noticed following notation in PHP. What does it mean?

```
$locales = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(Locales::class);
```

i have problems understanding parameter of makeInstance. Locales seems to be another static class. What means notation of

```
Locales::class
```

explicitly? What kind of parameter will it expect?

Comment: Well, would be crazy, calling variable or method as 'class', wouldn't it? Thought, 'class' is reserved as keyword for classes?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference — What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya you're wrong. It's a reference to the full namespaced class name.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php#migration55.new-features.class-name, you can use it to get the fully qualified name of a class.

In your case, let's assume the `Locale` class is defined like this:

file1.php

```
<?php
    namespace App\Core;

    class Locale {}

    echo Locale::class;     // output - App\Core\Locale
```

**In a separate file**, you could `require`/`autoload` the file,

file2.php

```
<?php

    require_once #pathToFile1/file1.php;

    use App\Core\Locale;

    echo Locale::class;        // output - App\Core\Locale
```

We can also see from this that we no longer have to save our class name in a variable as we can always call `Locale::class` and get going.

To address one of the comments on the question, yes, `class` is a keyword and using it for function name usually result in a `parse error`.. That changed in PHP 7 though...thus you can define a function and name it `class`, `function` etc. It's best not to do this though unless you think it's absolutely necessary.